# Change/update cookie value upon request

Tags: .net, vb.net, httprequest, httpresponse

**Trying to update an existing cookie on a site.**

Here is what i have tried:

```
 Private Sub UpdateCookie()
    Dim cookieContainer As CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
    Dim CookieChange As Cookie = New Cookie("cookieName", "coookieValue", "/", "myurl.com")
    cookieContainer.Add(CookieChange)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://myurl.com/"), HttpWebRequest)
    request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer

    Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim sourcecode As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
    TextBox1.Text = sourcecode
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by *update an existing cookie on a site* ? Servers set cookies, not clients.

Comment: @Crowcoder editing an existing cookies value. And yes clients can change the value og a cookie. For example opening the inspect element tab, pressing «application» , select domain and then edit your desired cookie

Comment: but that doesn't mean the server will accept it. At a glance it looks like what you are doing there is analogous to editing it in the browser. What is not working?

Comment: @Crowcoder trying to bypass tumblrs «eu agreement» page. Wich pops up when entering a tumblr page, but once u hit accept it saves a cookie so u dont have to see it everytime. So i was trying to bypass the eu agreement page by modifying the cookie value.

Comment: If tumblr engineers have any level of competence that will not work.

Comment: @Crowcoder go to tumblr , press get started, open f12, get the pfg cookie, and insert it into same page but ingonito, worked when i tested it

Comment: Well ok then I don't know. You may need to also add a user agent header. Try to recreate everything you see in the browser network tab request that works